# Ionic app shows only white blank screen in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app developed in Ionic it is working fine in Web and Android it is even in Google Play Store right now but when I try to run it on simulator or device it just show a blank white screen not even splashscreen. I try to debug it with Safari but it says there are no events to debug while app is open in device and simulator.

[image]

My Ionic config is :

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.9.1 (/Users/suatkarabacak/npm/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 17 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.1) : 0.14.0
   native-run                             : 1.0.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.5
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.3 Build version 11C29
```

I am just stuck at this position I am trying to find any tool to understand what is my mistake or problem.

Comment: Try to run app usin xCode you might be able to see the error in xCode console.

Comment: This is a little late -- but if you don't see the app show up in Safari's Develop menu, chances are you'll need to restart Safari. (I run into this condition all the time)

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: I truly can not remember the problem or solution but if you can provide more details I can try to help.